# active_record-acts_as and devise integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

i'm writing my first rails application using active_record-acts_as and devise. I have an User (devise authentication and actable)  , Client (act_as) and Owner (act_as).I overrided the registration_controller to add some extra fields in the devise form, fields like name, surname etc. that i need for Client and Owner. I'm trying to sign up both Client and Owner using the devise authentication of the User but adding other fields. I thought to define the authentication on the User to avoid duplicates in the schema. Is it possible to do this without define the devise controller of both Client and Owner?

client.rb

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :user
end
```

owner.rb

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class Utente < ActiveRecord::Base

 actable
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
      :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  resources :clients
  resources :users
  resources :owners
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should understand about the gem you are using is that, it buys you the idea of having empty columns. However it is necessary you note that, each details goes to its respective table.

Having said that, you can use rails authentication on any table where you hope to set authentication on.

Now based on the later part of your question, where you asked to avoid duplicates on your table, you set `validation` in your model, such that any of your model becomes:

```
class Utente < ActiveRecord::Base

 actable
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
      :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 validates :email, :uniqueness => true

end
```

You could see documentation of how you set validations on `active_record-acts_as` [here](https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as#usage)

Since its MTI with Devise, respective data goes to where it's suppose to be right out of the box, then I will suggest you set validations on other tables that `acts_as :user`, but on attributes that are not on the `actable` devise table. For example:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :user

  validates :school, :uniqueness => true
end
```